# How to use Hudson to securely request/receive an Android private key from another server?

Tags: android, encryption, hudson, code-signing, private-key

I would like to store the Android private key on a server different from my Hudson build server. Let's call it the Private Key server, or PK server for short. After receiving the private key, the .apk can be signed, and then the private key will be deleted.

More specifically:

- What kind of implementation is required on the PK server to do this?
- On the build server, what is needed in the Hudson build script to initiate the sending of the Android private key?

I assume this involves some sort of encryption protocol but I am unsure of how to implement it between these 2 systems.

Answer (score 0):

As you will be running this unattended in the CI server you will need a way of retrieving the keystore from your PK server without manually entering a password which will defeat your intention.

I would suggest you to keep the **keystore** in your PK server and create a service that takes an **unsigned APK** as argument and returns the **signed APK**. In this way your keystore never leaves the PK server.
This service can be invoked as a build step in your CI server.

Comment: Thank you - this could work, but I am worried about the size of the apk say for media apps. The larger it is, the longer this method will take.

Comment: Transferring forth and back over the LAN or even Internet should take a negligible amount of time unless you have an incredible big APK which would be problematic in other fronts as well.